# Apply function to each row in dataset when conditions are met

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a boolean variable (parent_boolean). If parent_boolean = True then I want to apply a function to table_name, if parent_boolean = False then I want to apply a different function to table_name in the data set. What is the easiest way to do this in DPLYR?

```
table_name    parent_table  parent_boolean column_count
 <chr>                                             <chr>                              <lgl>             <dbl>
1 table_1       table_1      TRUE                     1
2 table_2       table_1     FALSE                     3                                      

dp_child <- function(table_name, parent_table) { function runs SQL statement against database) 

dp_parent <- function(table_name) {function runs SQL statement against database)
```

I want to run the dp_parent function on each row that the table_name is the parent_table and I want to run the dp_child function on each row that the table_name is not the parent_table.

Comment: Can you provide minimally reproducible data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse` in while creating a new column using `mutate`:

```r
A <- c(T,F,F,T,T)
B <- LETTERS[1:5]
df <- data.frame(A,B)

library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(C = ifelse(A, paste0(B,1),paste0(B,"A")))

      A B  C
1  TRUE A A1
2 FALSE B BA
3 FALSE C CA
4  TRUE D D1
5  TRUE E E1
```

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: I am getting this error: Error: `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 2

Comment: @Onyambu, you're right, it works too but my point was to be explicite in the use of the `ifelse` statement in case the OP is a beginner in R.

Comment: Even for beginners, you cannot say if  `TRUE == TRUE` that is just not okay

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `ifelse()`, where a toy example is give as below

```
# two distinct function
f1 <- function(x) x**2
f2 <- function(x) -sqrt(x)

# apply function to column B according to value in column A
df <- data.frame(A = c(T,T,F,T),B = 1:4)
df <- within(df, C <- ifelse(A,f1(B),f2(B)))
```

such that

```
> df
      A B         C
1  TRUE 1  1.000000
2  TRUE 2  4.000000
3 FALSE 3 -1.732051
4  TRUE 4 16.000000
```

**EDIT**
with the data frame in your post, maybe you can try the code below

```
result <- apply(df, 1, function(v) {
  if (v["parent_boolean"]) {
    dp_parent(v["table_name"])
  } else {
    dp_child(v["table_name"],v["parent_table"])
  }
})
df <- cbind(df,result)
## or 
# add_column(df, result)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error: `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 2

Comment: @mrichey I updated my answer, so you can try if it can work

Comment: Thanks! The output appears to be an individual tibble for each row: row_counts      
 <tibble [1 × 1]>. Is there a way to fix this for the new column

Comment: @mrichey, how about using `cbind(df, result)` or `add_column(df, result)`? see my updates in the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @mrichey does it work? if yes, please feel free to upvote/accept the answer, otherwise, tell me what is needed further